# dbDacFx: supported databases

Tags: sql-server, msdeploy

I am trying to sync 2 databases, hosted on MSSQL 2014 and receive an "System.Exception: Database source is not a supported version of SQL Server".
I am using MsDeploy 3.6 - which seems to be most recent version of MsDeploy available, so, I am wondering - why it is not supporting latest database version on the marker? And where can I find which versions is supported (it seems that there MSSQL 2012 is supported, though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the SQL Server Data-Tier Application Framework.  Full DacPacFx usage tutorial -

http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/dbdacfx-provider-for-incremental-database-publishing

Comment: I recommend to use Web Platform installer to install ScriptDom, SQLSysClrTypes and dacframework - due to unknown reason downloaded versions was not working for me